# In what unit can I find TDateRec in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, delphi-12-athens

I'm trying to use `TDateRec` in Delphi, but I can't find the unit.

I found TDateRec on [docwiki where it explained Structured Types](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Athens/en/Structured_Types_(Delphi)).

Whenever I try to use it, I get an error:

> [dcc64 Error] E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'TDateRec'

I'm trying to use it as follow:

```
const
  Date1:TDateRec=(Year:2009;month:05;day:11);
```

Where can I find `TDateRec` so that Delphi knows about it when I use it?

Comment: `TDateRec` is just an example type used in the docwiki article describing how to declare record types. It's not a standard type that is part of the supplied libraries. If you want to use such a type, declare a type in your own code.

Comment: ohhh. That's really unfortunate. Thanks.

Comment: What functionality are you seeking? Have you checked [System.DateUtils.TDateTimeHelper](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Alexandria/en/System.DateUtils.TDateTimeHelper) functionality?

Comment: Why do you regard this as unfortunate? What actual problem are you trying to solve? And if the solution involves defining and using types, why is that unfortunate? Isn't that what programmers do.

Comment: I'm trying to find a nice way to declare a constant TDate

Comment: That record won't allow you to do that, because `TDate` is a floating point value (a rather terrible decision but that's another story!)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Turns out that `TDateRec` doesn't exist in Delphi. So it can't be found anywhere.

So what I was trying to do would never have worked. Do achieve what I was trying to do, I would need to create my own record such as:

```
type
   TDateRec = record
     Year: Integer;
     Month: 1..12;
     Day: 1..31;
   end;
```

And then the following code would be possible:

```
Date1: TDateRec = (Year:2009;month:05;day:11);
```

Comment: It would be better to delete the Q. It doesn't add anything valuable to future Google searches (but it does clutter the site).

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand I think it's valuable. I was literally searching "Delphi TDateRec unit" and "What unit is TDateRec in Delphi" and couldn't find anything on Google and I thought it was part of Delphi because I saw it in docwiki. I think it's reasonable to assume someone else might also make the same mistake and search for the same question.

Comment: I think it is pretty clear from the doc that the example itself declares the type: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JxmVR.png

Comment: Maybe for an experienced developer, but not a beginner.

Comment: I'm with @AndreasRejbrand here. The question has been asked on a false premise. And I disagree that you need to be experienced to read the documentation. This really adds nothing of use for future visitors.